# How do I create a document repository in Symfony2 by command?

Tags: php, symfony

How can I run a command for creating a repository file when the document has already been created?

```
doctrine:mongodb:generate:document
```

Comment: more explain please... What do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: `doctrine:mongodb:generate:repositories`